# convert update-rc.d command into chkconfig

Tags: command-line, chkconfig

I'm running CentOS 7.2 on my Cloud Account and following some tutorials to install Grafana.
I've almost finished install but got stuck when they asked me to execute this command which used to start the service on boot.

```
update-rc.d grafana-server defaults 95 10
```

Of course, i did it and error came out: `update-rc.d command not found.`
I tried to install it with yum but it didn't work too.
Is there anyway to "execute" this command or just convert it into chkconfig which i could execute it right away without any trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update-rc.d doesn't exist on Red Hat distros such as Fedora/CentOS/etc. The equivalent would be to use `chkconfig`, eg.

```
chkconfig grafana-server on
```

By default, `chkconfig` assumes levels 2345. Any runlevels not specified as on, will be marked as off; levels 016 by default. So you can specify runlevels:

```
chkconfig --level 345 grafana-server on
```

Comment: I didn't know about that :D Thank you.